# Conditional formatting in HTML Email Templates

Tags: email-template, html, email-alert

I need to display a message based on a condition which has to be formatted with bold style, add line breaks, etc. Using HTML markup inside IF condition is not working in HTML email templates.

For example,

```
{!IF(customObject.customField__c = 'Expected Value', '<BR><UL><LI>Item1</LI><LI>Item2</LI></UL>', '')}
```

However, the same IF condition works if the message to be displayed is plain text.

Do you have any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For HTML template, use div and set the style display conditionally

```
<div style="display: {!IF(customObject.customField__c = 'Expected Value', '' , 'none')}">
<BR><UL><LI>Item1</LI><LI>Item2</LI></UL>
</div>
```

Alternative solution for visualforce email template

try with `apex:ouptputpanel` and use rendered attribute to show the content

```
<apex:outputpanel rendered="{!customObject.customField__c = 'Expected Value'}">
<BR><UL><LI>Item1</LI><LI>Item2</LI></UL>
</apex:outputpanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Is there a way to do this in HTML email template?

Comment: @VijayPrakash check the updated answer