# Custom Setting List That works as a switch question

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a custom setting list called `LPGCalculatorSettings__c` that has a `RollupTriggerSwitch` that has a value of false. No how can I make it like a switch where in it will turn on/off my Trigger.

This is My trigger

```
trigger TotalOpportunityProductTrigger on OpportunityLineItem (after insert, after update, after delete) {

TotalOpportunityProductTriggerHandler tp = new TotalOpportunityProductTriggerHandler();

if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter){
tp.TotalField(Trigger.new);
}
else if (Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter){
tp.TotalField(Trigger.new);
}
else if(Trigger.isDelete && Trigger.isAfter){
tp.TotalField(Trigger.old);
}


}
```

Comment: what is the name of this record and field name in custom setting ?

Comment: LPGCalculatorSettings__c is the name of the custom setting and within the value__c there is a RollupTriggerSwitch that has a value of false @Ratan

Comment: JMDF.. check my answer and let me know if that make sense to you or not.

Comment: @Ratan Well actually it does not make any sense. Like how will I make it the custom trigger true, Things like that. Can you explain to me how this works. Thanks for the reply man. Really Appreciate it

Comment: now this becomes confused. can you please clarify what you are looking for? in your question you are saying something else

Comment: Well actually @Ratan your answer looks right. I just don't know how this switch works. But just to clear it up, what I need is Use a custom setting value ‘RollupTriggerSwtich’ in ‘LPG Calculator Settings' to control whether to calculate those values in trigger.

Comment: ok. let me clear things. you have a custom setting ie. `LPGCalculatorSettings__c` it has a custom field `value__c` it's type is checkbox. Now you created a record in this custom setting with name `RollupTriggerSwitch` and `value__c` equals to false. So whenever  `value__c` equals to false then you don't want to run the trigger correct? Can you check if my understanding correct or not?

Comment: It's actually correct but my value__c is a Text. You understood it 100% @Ratan

Comment: I suggest change this text field to checkbox. else just check in condition like `objCalSetting.value__c == 'true'` then only execute trigger code

Comment: Hi @Ratan I tried your code below but it throws an error " Condition expression must be of type Boolean at line 8 column 5 "

Comment: It's already working @Ratan changed my value__c to checkbox. Just one last question, How can I test this?

Comment: yeah you just checkbox checked or unchecked and test the trigger functionality if it is working or not.. thats it

Comment: @Ratan So I'll add a custom field in my page? is that it? Sorry I am lost with this one. First time to experience custom settings.

Comment: you need to create a record in custom setting with name `RollupTriggerSwitch` and value__c true.. you can see there will be manage button in custom setting. There you can click on new and able to create record

Comment: @Ratan How can I do that? I just upvoted your post.

Comment: JMDF.. check this answer http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/143997/18731 how to accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
trigger TotalOpportunityProductTrigger on OpportunityLineItem (after insert, after update, after delete) {

    // get the record from custom setting using getValues method and pass the name of record
    LPGCalculatorSettings__c  objCalSetting = LPGCalculatorSettings__c .getValues('RollupTriggerSwitch');

    //if your custo setting value is true then only execute trigger code
    if(objCalSetting.value__c == 'true'){
        TotalOpportunityProductTriggerHandler tp = new TotalOpportunityProductTriggerHandler();

        if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter){
            tp.TotalField(Trigger.new);
        }
        else if (Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter){
            tp.TotalField(Trigger.new);
        }
        else if(Trigger.isDelete && Trigger.isAfter){
            tp.TotalField(Trigger.old);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing that prevents you from doing something like this

```
List<LPGCalculatorSettings__c> myLPGCalcValues = LPGCalculatorSettings__c.getall().values();
TotalOpportunityProductTriggerHandler tp = new TotalOpportunityProductTriggerHandler();
     if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter){
          if(myLPGCalcValues[0].RollupTriggerSwitch == true){
              tp.TotalField(Trigger.new);
          }
      }
```